# How to add padding-left without moving centered div content?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with content centered using two sections set to left 50% and left -50%. I want to add padding-left to a caret image so that it slides to the right 10 px without shoving the rest of the content over. I know it has something to do with the div content getting wider once the 10px are added, but I am not sure how to anchor the left-hand side of the content.

> Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/mowsie2k/pen/gOvdPLj

Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("bg1.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar,
.navbar-news {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-news-outer,
.navbar-news-inner {
  margin: 0mm;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-news-outer {
  left: 50%
}

.navbar-news-inner {
  left: -50%;
}

.navbar-news a,
.navbar-news i {
  color: bisque;
  transition: color .3s ease-out;
  transition: padding-left .3s ease-out;
}

.navbar-news a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.navbar-news a:hover i {
  color: blueviolet;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-news">
  <div class="navbar-news-outer">
    <div class="navbar-news-inner">
      <span>
      Newest Blog Post: Cybersecurity in the Era of Cloud Infrastructure <a>READ HERE <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `padding-left`, I'd advise using a `translateX` via the `transform` function.

The meaningful changes are here:

```css
.navbar-news a, .navbar-news i {
  color: bisque;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out, color .3s ease-out;
}

.navbar-news a:hover i {
  color: blueviolet;
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

### Demo

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
body {
    background-image: url("bg1.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar, .navbar-news {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    font-size: small;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-news-outer, .navbar-news-inner {
    margin: 0mm;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-news-outer{
    left: 50%
}
.navbar-news-inner{
    left: -50%;
}

.navbar-news a, .navbar-news i {
    color: bisque;
    transition: transform .3s ease-out, color .3s ease-out;
}

.navbar-news a:hover {
    color: blueviolet;
}

.navbar-news a:hover i {
    color: blueviolet;
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar-news">
        <div class="navbar-news-outer">
            <div class="navbar-news-inner">
                <span>
                    Newest Blog Post: Cybersecurity in the Era of Cloud Infrastructure <a>READ HERE <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also appreciated the tip combining the transition lines, I am a CSS caveman.

Answer (score 2):

Use `transformX` instead of adding padding.

```css
.navbar-news a:hover i {
    color: blueviolet;
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

Change the transition animation too

```css
.navbar-news a, .navbar-news i {
    color: bisque;
    transition: color .3s ease-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: SO tells me Andy beat you by a few seconds so I think I'm meant to mark his correct. Thank you for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it very much.